# Exists S4 class element in a list

Tags: r, list, find, exists, r-s4

I have a list with S4 objects. I need to check if one S4 object is present in that list. I have tried with some alternatives found in this page without success:

I tried with exists:

```
exists(foo,where=my_list)

Error in list2env(list(<S4 object of class "Atributo">, <S4 object of class "Atributo">,  
;names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

With match:

```
match(foo, my_list)

'match' requires vector arguments
```

The binary operator of match gives the same result %in%:

```
foo %in% my_list

'match' requires vector arguments
```

And is.element:

```
is.element(foo,my_list)

Error in match(el, set, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

For example I have created 5 elements and made a list with only 3 of them. I need to know if one specific element is in the list:

```
setClass("foo", representation = representation(bar = "numeric"))

one <- new("foo", bar = 12)
two <- new("foo", bar = 13)
three <- new("foo", bar = 14)
four <- new("foo", bar = 15)
five <- new("foo", bar = 16)

mylist <- list(one,two,three)
```

I would like to check if an specific element exists in the list for example:

```
usefull_function(four,my_list)

FALSE

usefull_function(two,my_list)

TRUE
```

I know if they are S4 elements I can check if the environment exists in the list of environments. ¿How would be an elegant/fast way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `sapply`, `any` and `is` should work.

```
setClass("foo", representation = representation(bar = "numeric"))

baz <- new("foo", bar = 42)
mylist <- list("hello", baz, 13)


any(sapply(mylist, is, class2 = "foo"))
```

Regarding object names within a list, I can only think of two ways

**Add names when list is constructed**

```
mylist <- list(one=one,two=two,three=three)
"one" %in% names(mylist)
```

**Compare object elements**

```
mylist <- list(one,two,three)
any(sapply(mylist, function(x) identical(one, x)))
[1] TRUE

any(sapply(mylist, function(x) identical(four, x)))
[1] FALSE
```

**NOTE** - this second approach assumes the elements within the objects are distinct so preferably you would use the 1st approach.

Comment: The problem with that implementation is that I will always have "foo" class objects in the list. For example I have an "baz" and a "baz2" and need to check if exists "baz" rather than "baz2"

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez, oh, so you are looking for the object name as opposed to the class? or both?

Comment: The name doesn't really matter. For example I have 10 "foo" class elements and only 5 of them in the list, I need to check if one element is in the list. The exact name of how it was declared doesn't really matters.

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez perhaps you can elaborate more in your question and demonstrate where this would fail.   Is it that you want to check if an object is also in a list?  e.g. `baz` exists and `baz` is also in `mylist`?

Comment: there I tried to explain better. The actual solution with any, sapply and is would give always TRUE

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez where in your list did the names `one`, `two` and `three` occur?  You can simply add the names: `names(mylist) <- c("one","two","three")`. Then you can do `any(grepl("one",names(mylist)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem but i think you should modify your s4 class definition
from

```
setClass("foo", representation = representation(bar = "numeric"))
```

to

```
setClass("foo", representation = representation(name='character',bar = "numeric"))
```

then

```
one <- new("foo",name='one', bar = 12)
two <- new("foo", name='two', bar = 13)
three <- new("foo",name='three', bar = 14)
four <- new("foo", name='four',bar = 15)
five <- new("foo", name='five',bar = 16)

mylist <- list(one,two,three)
```

then your can design function to exact all the names from object and  Compare their names